# How to achieve a dashed underline using chunk.setUnderline?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, underline

I use `SAXItexthandler` to achieve custom underlining of specified thickness, color & specified Y position using the below code. So basically i have different strings in multiple itext cells in a itext row and the below code helps me to do the underlining for every chunk where every chunk is embedded within a cell and it works perfectly fine.

```
Color c = Color.decode(custom_color);
currentChunk.setUnderline(c, thickness, 0.01f, ypos, 0.01f, PdfContentByte.LINE_CAP_BUTT);
```

Now is there a way i can just make the underline dashed? I use the above code heavily and we have a new requirement for dashed underlines only in a few places. So i would like to know if i can achieve it using `setUnderline` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic tags on chunks:

1. Set the tag on relevant chunks
2. Create a class that extends `PdfPageEventHelper` and add it to the writer
3. Write the code that makes the underlining job on the `onGenericTag` method
4. In the `onGenericTag` method you have the surrounding rect of the chunk: you can draw a line directly on the PdfContentByte using a dashed style or whatever style you desire.