# Convert HTML style (dotted underline) to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I am trying to generate PDF from below HTML i.e. a text with dotted underline. (Below is sample actual HTML is much bigger)

```
<u style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;text-decoration: none;"> Hello </u>
```

as explained in [How to convert HTML to PDF using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp) . The output is supposed to have a dotted line which I can see in the HTML file, however the PDF generated by iTextSharp shows a normal underline and not a dotted underline. Here is my complete method

```
   public void UsingXMLWorker()
    {            
        Byte[] bytes;

        //Create a stream that we can write to, in this case a MemoryStream
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {

                    //Open the document for writing
                    doc.Open();

                    //sample HTML and CSS
                    var example_html = @"<u style=""border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;text-decoration: none;"" >&nbsp;Hello&nbsp;</u>";

                    using (var srHtml = new StringReader(example_html))
                    {
                        //Parse the HTML
                        iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                    }

                    //var example_html = @"<u class=""dottedBorder"">&nbsp;Hello&nbsp;</u>";
                    //var example_css = @".dottedBorder{border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;text-decoration: none;font-size:38px;}";
                    //using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)))
                    //{
                    //    using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                    //    {

                    //        //Parse the HTML
                    //        iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                    //    }
                    //}
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }


        var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
    }
```

I even tried other methods like below code still I see a PDF generated with a normal underline as opposed to a dotted underline. What I am missing here ?

```
                    var example_html = @"<u class=""dottedBorder"">&nbsp;Hello&nbsp;</u>";
                    var example_css = @".dottedBorder{border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;text-decoration: none;font-size:38px;}";
                    using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                        {

                            //Parse the HTML
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CSS conformance list](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm), borders are only supported on table cells.

The line you are seeing is actually the `<u>` tag's default bottom border and your `text-decoration` code is actually being overwritten by the default code for a `<u>` tag. If you watch the `ResolveStyles` method in `iTextSharp\tool\xml\css\StyleAttrCSSResolver.cs`, the top chunk (around 170 in 5.5.6) that sets keys and values for `tagCss` correctly finds and sets your property. The next block of code after that, however, special-cases certain HTML tags and forces some rules upon then.

```
// inherit css from parent tags, as defined in provided CssInheritanceRules or if property = inherit
IDictionary<String, String> css = t.CSS;
if (t.Name != null)
{
    if (t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.I) || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.CITE)
        || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.EM) || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.VAR)
        || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.DFN) || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.ADDRESS)) {
            tagCss[CSS.Property.FONT_STYLE] = CSS.Value.ITALIC;
    }
    else if (t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.B) || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.STRONG)) {
        tagCss[CSS.Property.FONT_WEIGHT] = CSS.Value.BOLD;
    }
    else if (t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.U) || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.INS)) {
        tagCss[CSS.Property.TEXT_DECORATION] = CSS.Value.UNDERLINE;
    }
    else if (t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.S) || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.STRIKE) 
             || t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.DEL)) {
                 tagCss[CSS.Property.TEXT_DECORATION] = CSS.Value.LINE_THROUGH;
    }
    else if (t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.BIG)) {
        tagCss[CSS.Property.FONT_SIZE] = CSS.Value.LARGER;
    }
    else if (t.Name.Equals(HTML.Tag.SMALL)) {
        tagCss[CSS.Property.FONT_SIZE] = CSS.Value.SMALLER;
    }
}
```

Since this block happens *after* your CSS you'll see that you can't remove an underline on a `<u>` tag because it will always be turned back on. Similarly, you also can't un-bold a `<strong>` tag, un-italic an `<em>` or explicitly set a font size on a `<big>` tag (I forgot that was actually a tag!) unless you have a parent container's font size set.

So unfortunately, short of modifying the source I'm not really sure that what you are looking for is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the update Chris. I tried using different HTML tags but still the issue is there.  For example with    <div style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;" >&nbsp;Hello stackoverflow how are you?&nbsp;</div>. Any suggestions ?  I think I will go with your other suggestion as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260730/how-do-you-underline-text-with-dashedline-in-itext-pdf and I will mix my HTML accordingly.

Comment: Like I said, you can only change the border style on a table cell, nothing else, so a div wouldn't help you. You'll need to mix it with the other one (that I forgot I wrote about even!)