# Table on same line

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, itextpdf

I use itextpdf-5.5.6 in my publisher project. I want to set a table on same line that a paragraph or phrase or text ?

Something like that :

In My Para |MY TAB OF ONE COLUMN| is present on a same line.

is it possible ?

Comment: Using a `PdfPTable`, this is impossible, but if you want a table with 1 column *and a single row*, then it's very easy to achieve this. Please confirm if a single row is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I want use only 1 column and a single row in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a table. What you need, is a generic tag event. Take a look at the answer by Chris Haas to this question: [How do you underline text with dashedline in ITEXT PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260730/how-do-you-underline-text-with-dashedline-in-itext-pdf)

In this answer, he describes how to use a page event often referred to as the *generic tag* functionality. You can find a Java example here: [DashedUnderline](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/DashedUnderline)

In this example, we use the generic tag functionality to underline a `Chunk`, but instead of drawing a dashed line, you can easily draw a rectangle.

You create a chunk like this and set a generic tag:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This chunk needs to be inside a rectangle ");
chunk.setGenericTag("");
```

You can make this `chunk` part of a `Paragraph`:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("[Before]");
p.add(chunk);
p.add("[After]");
```

This will only work if you declare a page event like this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
writer.setPageEvent(new DrawRectangle());
```

Of course, we need to implement the `DrawRectangle` class;

```
public class DrawRectangle extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    @Override
    public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        canvas.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
        canvas.stroke();
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
}
```

For more inspiration, take a look at the [MovieYears](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=97) example taken from [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book). It adds ellipses and movie clips at specific places: [movie_years.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/movie_years.pdf)

In this case, the `onGenericTag()` method is created like this:

```
class GenericTags extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document pdfDocument,
            Rectangle rect, String text) {
        if ("strip".equals(text))
            strip(writer.getDirectContent(), rect);
        else if ("ellipse".equals(text))
            ellipse(writer.getDirectContentUnder(), rect);
        else
            countYear(text);
    }

    public void strip(PdfContentByte content, Rectangle rect) {
        content.rectangle(rect.getLeft() - 1, rect.getBottom() - 5f,
                rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight() + 8);
        content.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom() - 2,
                rect.getWidth() - 2, rect.getHeight() + 2);
        float y1 = rect.getTop() + 0.5f;
        float y2 = rect.getBottom() - 4;
        for (float f = rect.getLeft(); f < rect.getRight() - 4; f += 5) {
            content.rectangle(f, y1, 4f, 1.5f);
            content.rectangle(f, y2, 4f, 1.5f);
        }
        content.eoFill();
    }

    public void ellipse(PdfContentByte content, Rectangle rect) {
        content.saveState();
        content.setRGBColorFill(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
        content.ellipse(rect.getLeft() - 3f, rect.getBottom() - 5f,
                rect.getRight() + 3f, rect.getTop() + 3f);
        content.fill();
        content.restoreState();
    }

    TreeMap<String, Integer> years = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    public void countYear(String text) {
        Integer count = years.get(text);
        if (count == null) {
            years.put(text, 1);
        }
        else {
            years.put(text, count + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, we check the value that was passed to the `setGenericTag()` method here. Also: we don't always use the method to draw something. In this case, we also use the generic tag functionality to count things.

Comment: Thank you Bruno to spend timo for me, I avanced my project with this solution.