# How during work itext find out coordinates text?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I want to know the coordinates of the text that is added to the page. 
And apply some canvas to this text. (for example custom underline or strikethrough or text inside the triangle)

I only need certain words

```
List<String> listString = new ArraList();

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));

Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
for(String s:listString)
   //**underlineWord** hidden it will be removed
 if( s.contains("**underlineWord**")){
     s.replace("**underlineWord**","");
    Text text = new Text(s)
    Float[] coords = getCoords(text)
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(...);
     setCustomUderline(coords)
 }


 doc.add(new Paragraph(text) );
```

I know about PdfCanvasProcessor, but I don't use it because I will not know about certain words, (which contain `**underlineWord**`)

Comment: Please explain more clearly. Having read your question multiple times I still have no idea what it is about.

Comment: @mkl  i want to add canvas on certain text which contain tag,for example <u>hello</u>.And when i add word in doc, I want this word to underline with canvas or strikethrough

Comment: @mkl help please)

Comment: For underlining simply use the `com.itextpdf.layout.property.Property.UNDERLINE` property with a `com.itextpdf.layout.property.Underline` value.

Comment: @mkl i know about this. I just gave an example with this. I need to use canvas on certain words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iText7 you implement such tasks using a custom `Renderer`. The technique is shown in the [`DashedUnderline` example](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/events/DashedUnderline.java):

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.add(new Paragraph("This text is not underlined"));
Text text1 = new Text("This text is underlined with a solid line");
text1.setUnderline(1, -3);
doc.add(new Paragraph(text1));
Text text2 = new Text("This text is underlined with a dashed line");
text2.setNextRenderer(new DashedLineTextRenderer(text2));
doc.add(new Paragraph(text2));
doc.close();
```

i.e. you merely set a custom `Renderer` to the `Text` bit in question. In the example at hand the custom `Renderer` class is

```
protected class DashedLineTextRenderer extends TextRenderer {
    public DashedLineTextRenderer(Text textElement) {
        super(textElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.draw(drawContext);
        Rectangle rect = this.getOccupiedAreaBBox();
        PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();
        canvas
                .saveState()
                .setLineDash(3, 3)
                .moveTo(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom() - 3)
                .lineTo(rect.getRight(), rect.getBottom() - 3)
                .stroke()
                .restoreState();
    }
}
```

As you see you can override `draw` to first call the `super` implementation to have the text drawn normally. After that you can retrieve the area used for drawing the text by calling `getOccupiedAreaBBox` and use it for your task, be it for decorating the text or merely storing the position somewhere.

---

If you wonder why this example is in the **`events`** sub-package... the example corresponds to an iText5 example, and in iText5 you implement such a task by means of setting a generic tag to the `Chunk` in question and listening for that generic tag in the `onGenericTag` method of a page event listener, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29263032/1729265) for an example.

---

In a comment you asked

> Can i do it with table? (draw border with help canvas)

Yes, again you use the associated renderers for that, e.g. see the [`DottedLineCell` example](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/tables/DottedLineCell.java):

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.add(new Paragraph("Table event"));
Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(3)).useAllAvailableWidth();
table.setNextRenderer(new DottedLineTableRenderer(table, new Table.RowRange(0, 2)));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("A1")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("A2")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("A3")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("B1")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("B2")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("B3")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("C1")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("C2")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("C3")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
doc.add(table);
doc.add(new Paragraph("Cell event"));
table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(1)).useAllAvailableWidth();
Cell cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Test"));
cell.setNextRenderer(new DottedLineCellRenderer(cell));
cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
doc.add(table);

doc.close();
```

Here the first table shows how to do this using the table renderer after turning off standard table cell borders while the second table shows how to do this using the cell renderers.

The customized renderer classes are

```
private class DottedLineTableRenderer extends TableRenderer {
    public DottedLineTableRenderer(Table modelElement, Table.RowRange rowRange) {
        super(modelElement, rowRange);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawChildren(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.drawChildren(drawContext);
        PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();
        canvas.setLineDash(3f, 3f);
        // first horizontal line
        CellRenderer[] cellRenderers = rows.get(0);
        canvas.moveTo(cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getLeft(),
                cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getTop());
        canvas.lineTo(cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getRight(),
                cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getTop());

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            cellRenderers = rows.get(i);
            // horizontal lines
            canvas.moveTo(cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getX(),
                    cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getY());
            canvas.lineTo(cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getRight(),
                    cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getBottom());
            // first vertical line
            Rectangle cellRect = cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox();
            canvas.moveTo(cellRect.getLeft(), cellRect.getBottom());
            canvas.lineTo(cellRect.getLeft(), cellRect.getTop());
            // vertical lines
            for (int j = 0; j < cellRenderers.length; j++) {
                cellRect = cellRenderers[j].getOccupiedArea().getBBox();
                canvas.moveTo(cellRect.getRight(), cellRect.getBottom());
                canvas.lineTo(cellRect.getRight(), cellRect.getTop());
            }
        }
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

and

```
private class DottedLineCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    public DottedLineCellRenderer(Cell modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.draw(drawContext);
        drawContext.getCanvas().setLineDash(3f, 3f);
        drawContext.getCanvas().rectangle(this.getOccupiedArea().getBBox());
        drawContext.getCanvas().stroke();
    }
}
```

respectively.

---

As explained by [Alexey Subach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333458/alexey-subach) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56103462/1729265), a complete customization of a `Renderer` should also *override the `getNextRenderer()` method.* In particular if an area break might occur in the object in question, this is necessary, otherwise the customization only works in the first area as the OP has observed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I LOVE YOU! And where do you get all this information? Maybe there is a book?

Comment: Can i do it with table? (draw border with help canvas) :)

Comment: *"where do you get all this information"* - well, 
I was sure it had to be a renderer (because what else could it be) but admittedly I found this very example only because I knew that in itext 5 one would do that using generic tags: So I looked for itext 5 examples using generic tags, found the itext 5 variant, and from there switched to the itext 7 example.

Comment: @forseti420 *"Can i do it with table? (draw border with help canvas)"* - I assume you can completely customize table borders by changing the cell render. There likely even is a method in the renderer for drawing borders which you can override.

Comment: @forseti420 I edited my answer to include and reference examples for table and table cell renderer customization.

Comment: This does not work if the table is more than one page. :( Can i fix it?

Comment: Please make that a question in its own right (in which you can reference both this question and the itext example code) and create a short test program illustrating the issue.