# Draw custom borders for table spanning across more than one page in itext7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

If I do like it:
[How during work itext find out coordinates text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960525/how-during-work-itext-find-out-coordinates-text/56044933?noredirect=1#comment98819854_56044933)

Everything works. But if i create table more one page, nothing is drawn:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Table event"));
        Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(3)).useAllAvailableWidth();
        table.setNextRenderer(new DottedLineTableRenderer(table, new Table.RowRange(0, 0)));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\n" )).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("A2")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("A3")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));

        doc.add(table);
        doc.close();
```

Custom Renderer class:

```
 private class DottedLineTableRenderer extends TableRenderer {
    public DottedLineTableRenderer(Table modelElement, Table.RowRange rowRange) {
        super(modelElement, rowRange);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawChildren(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.drawChildren(drawContext);
        PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();
        canvas.setLineDash(3f, 3f);
        // first horizontal line
        CellRenderer[] cellRenderers = rows.get(0);
        canvas.moveTo(cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getLeft(),
                cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getTop());
        canvas.lineTo(cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getRight(),
                cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getTop());

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            cellRenderers = rows.get(i);
            // horizontal lines
            canvas.moveTo(cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getX(),
                    cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getY());
            canvas.lineTo(cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getRight(),
                    cellRenderers[cellRenderers.length - 1].getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getBottom());
            // first vertical line
            Rectangle cellRect = cellRenderers[0].getOccupiedArea().getBBox();
            canvas.moveTo(cellRect.getLeft(), cellRect.getBottom());
            canvas.lineTo(cellRect.getLeft(), cellRect.getTop());
            // vertical lines
            for (int j = 0; j < cellRenderers.length; j++) {
                cellRect = cellRenderers[j].getOccupiedArea().getBBox();
                canvas.moveTo(cellRect.getRight(), cellRect.getBottom());
                canvas.lineTo(cellRect.getRight(), cellRect.getTop());
            }
        }
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

Can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Accessing `rows` is a bad idea. Is the end goal to only draw non-standard borders?

Comment: @Alexey Subach, yes, i need draw only non-standard borders.(change color, change tilt angle etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using has many assumptions about how the implementation works internally in `TableRenderer`.

As in your code you are drawing a dashed border I must point you to `DashedBorder` class which you can already use out of the box:

```
Border customBorder = new DashedBorder(ColorConstants.RED, 2);
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("A2")).setBorder(customBorder));
```

You can also implement your custom border class in the following way:

```
private static class CustomBorder extends Border {
    protected CustomBorder(Color color, float width) {
        super(color, width);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(PdfCanvas canvas, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, Side defaultSide, float borderWidthBefore, float borderWidthAfter) {
    }

    @Override
    public void drawCellBorder(PdfCanvas canvas, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, Side defaultSide) {
        canvas.
                saveState().
                setStrokeColor(transparentColor.getColor());
        transparentColor.applyStrokeTransparency(canvas);
        canvas.
                setLineDash(3, 3).
                setLineWidth(width).
                moveTo(x1, y1).
                lineTo(x2, y2).
                stroke().
                restoreState();
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return Border.DASHED;
    }
}
```

Then just create an instance and use it in `setBorder`:

```
 Border customBorder = new CustomBorder(ColorConstants.RED, 2);
 table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("A2")).setBorder(customBorder));
```

Comment: If the flexibility of the custom `Border` class is not enough for you then you will have to ask your question clearly and explain the goal you want to achieve precisely. The best way would be to ask a new question.

Comment: @ Alexey Subach , thanks, but I really need more flexibility

Comment: @heavywar please try to explain/draw what you are trying to achieve that cannot be done with custom border class then :)

Comment: i can't find out where is drawn cell or row. and if i change lineTo(x2+10, y2).
Change everything

Comment: @ Alexey Subach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101827/draw-custom-borders-for-table-with-more-flexibility-in-itext7